# Select value without button

Tags: javascript, validation, select

I have a selection and i need to set validatoin for the selected without onclick function.
So if i selected Healthcare I can innerHTML an information in paragraph without clicking on button.

```
<select name="industry" id="industry">
    <option value="none"> </option>
    <option value="1">Healthcare</option>
    <option value="2">Mining</option>
    <option value="3">Power</option>
    <option value="4">Audit</option>
    <option value="5">Accounting</option>
    <option value="6">IT</option>
    <option value="7">Telecommunications</option>
    <option value="8">Justice</option>
    <option value="9">Insurance</option>
    <option value="10">International Organizations/Embassies</option>
    <option value="100">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution in pure Javascript:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('industry');
var p = document.getElementById('paragraph')

select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  p.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
})
```

```html
<select name="industry" id="industry">
    <option value="none"> </option>
    <option value="1">Healthcare</option>
    <option value="2">Mining</option>
    <option value="3">Power</option>
    <option value="4">Audit</option>
    <option value="5">Accounting</option>
    <option value="6">IT</option>
    <option value="7">Telecommunications</option>
    <option value="8">Justice</option>
    <option value="9">Insurance</option>
    <option value="10">International Organizations/Embassies</option>
    <option value="100">Other</option>
</select>

<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Comment: Still working in 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```js
document.querySelector('#ice-cream').onchange = changeEventHandler;

function changeEventHandler(event) {
  const span = document.querySelector('#text');   
  if (!event.target.value) span.innerHTML = 'Please Select One';   
  else span.innerHTML = 'You like ' + event.target.value + ' ice cream.';
}
```

```html
<label>Choose an ice cream flavor:
    <select id="ice-cream" name="ice-cream">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    </select>
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="text"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery event and use

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#industry").change(function(){ 
        //$("#paragraph_id").text("your text"); 
        // or $("#paragraph_id").append("your text");

    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: i dont know jquery that well so i try no to use it, any other thing i can use in JS6?

Comment: @Anna, clearshot66's solution is OK, but it's written in jQuery. If you're not OK with this library, I have added solution in pure Javascript

Comment: JQuery is less code for the same effect. All you'd do is import the library and run it on your page. But pure JS6 would be as he stated above. Just because you don't know it well doesn't mean it's not a good thing to learn and pick up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain js to do this

```
document.querySelector('select[name="industry"]').onchange=function(event){
    switch(event.target.value){
      case "1":
            document.querySelector("#paragraph").innerHTML = "Information to display"
    break;
    default:
            document.querySelector("#paragraph").innerHTML = "default message"
    break;
  }
};
```